# Adjusting PixelRatio in React Native Manually

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have developed an according to my phone. But on other phones, due to different PixelRatio, it seems radically different.

I know we can only get the PixelRatio of a particular device but is there any way to set/adjust it?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's a hardware property.  You have to adjust your designs based on the PixelRatio of the device.